# How to take string input in different lines?

Tags: c, string, input

I wanna take some strings as input in 5 different lines.There is no limit about how many words a line can contain.But I want 5 lines.How can I do it?Please help me.

Example:The program will be like the following one

```
How many Line?

5

Enter 5 line:

hi i am john

i am new to c programming.

in have problem in string.

i can not take input

pleas help me.thanks a lot.
```

Here is my code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
    int line,i;
    char *string;
    printf("How many line?\n");
    scanf("%d",&line);
    for(i=0;i<line;i++)
    {
        gets(string);
    }
    printf("You entered:\n");
    for(i=0;i<line;i++)
    {
      puts(string);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

In my code it is just taking (n-1) line.Like if i give line 4 it takes 3 line and print the only the last line for 4 times.How can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow is not here to do your work for you. Please write your own code. If you encounter specific problems then come back, post the code and ask a specific question.

Comment: srry for that......i did it but it's not working.here is my code

Comment: Please update your question (click "edit" at the bottom of the question body). Don't add it to the comments as it can't be formatted and may be missed by others. And please describe your problem in more detail (not just "it's not working"). For example sample input, expected output and actual output. Or whatever incorrect behaviour your program is exhibiting.

Comment: See [Why `gets()` is too dangerous to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).  Don't use it.

Comment: One problem is that `scanf("%d", &line)` leaves a newline in the input buffer.  And the first `gets()` — which should be `fgets()` — reads the newline.  Another problem is that you haven't initialized `string` to point at any storage; you should be using `char string[4096];` or something similar.

Comment: the system function: gets() has long since been depreciated and is actually removed in the latest C standard.   Suggest using fgets()

Answer (score 3):

The bug in your code is that you have allocated memory for the character string to store the user input.

Here in the code `char *string` is a pointer, which points to the lastly entered string from the user input. Hence you get the last string as the output instead of fetching all the strings.

Change your code as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int line,i;
    char string[50][80];
    printf("How many line?\n");
    scanf("%d",&line);

    for(i=0;i<line;i++)
    {   
        scanf("%s", string[i]);
    }
    printf("You entered:\n");
    for(i=0;i<line;i++)
    {   
        puts(string[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code the maximum number of lines (`rows`) that can be read to set to `50` and the maximum width of each line is set to `80`.

If you are not sure of the maximum number of lines to be read or width of each line, then you should allocate memory for each line read dynamically using `malloc` and free them at the end of the program before return using `free`.

Also avoid using `gets()` for these [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: I changed it char *string to char string[1000].But still it is taking (n-1) line and printing only the last line.

Comment: `string` should be a `2-D` array. `char string[1000]` will store only one line of the input, which is the last line. Use `char string[x][y] and also change gets() to scanf`

Comment: scanf() will not do the job, as it stops at the first occurance of any white space.   Suggest using fgets()

Answer (score 1):

Rather than statically specifying a 2D array, you are better served by specifying an array of pointers and then allocating memory for each string added to the array. While `fgets` or `getline` is preferred, there is nothing wrong with allocating memory with `scanf`. (**Note:** the current version of `scanf` uses `m` prior to the conversion specifier for allocation, windows and earlier version used `a` for this purpose). When using `scanf` to allocate, `scanf` expects a pointer argument of type `char **` to hold the allocated string. When you allocate memory, regardless of how, **you** are responsible for **freeing** the memory when it is no longer required. Taking that into consideration, your code could be written as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXD 64

int main() {

    char *string[MAXD];
    int line = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf ("\nHome many lines: ");
    scanf ("%d%*c", &line);

    if (line > MAXD) {  /* validate line <= MAXD pointers */
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: request exceeds %d limit.\n", MAXD);
        line = MAXD;
    }

    /* scanf will allocate if given 'm' ('a' on Win & earlier versions) 
    as part of the specification before the conversion specifier */
    for (i = 0; i < line; i++) {
        printf ("\n input: ");
        scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &string[i]);
    }

    printf ("\nYou entered:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < line; i++)
        printf ("  string[%d] : %s\n", i, string[i]);

    printf ("\n");

    /* free the memory allocated by scanf */
    for (i = 0; i < line; i++)
        free (string[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_string_dyn

Home many lines: 4

 input: this is line 1

 input: this is line 2

 input: this is line 3

 input: this is line 4

You entered:

  string[0] : this is line 1
  string[1] : this is line 2
  string[2] : this is line 3
  string[3] : this is line 4
```

You can adjust the number of pointers by adjusting the `MAXD` define. (you can also dynamically allocate and reallocate them as necessary, but that is beyond the scope of your question)

Comment: Did you read the note? Not all versions of `scanf` use `m` and some non-compliant compilers do not even support it. Generally windows uses `a`, but with **codeblocks** all bets are off.